# Linux RAR - Русские символы (кириллица)

Tags: linux, кодировка, rar

Пытаюсь на Centos -

```
echo "Добавить русские комментарии к архиву" | rar c test.rar
```

И в итоге получаются пустые квадратики вместо символов, как сделать корректно?

Пробовал так -

```
echo "Добавить русские комментарии в архив" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t WINDOWS-1251 | | rar c test.rar
```

Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Покажите и то, как вы их потом смотрите.

Answer (score 0):

Имел ту же самую дилемму и никакие действия не помогали, как и "игры" с кодировкой.

Связался E. Roshal (создателем rar) и спустя несколько дней он предложил рабочее решение, а именно ключ `-scfc`.

Вводим:

```
echo "Русские символы" | rar c -scfc test.rar
```

И буквы будут отображаться корректно.